# Notification showing on my android without a specific App

Tags: applications, security, notifications, xiaomi, virus

I have a Xiaomi Note 9s phone updated with the latest security patched running

MIUI Global 12.0.4.0(RJWMIXM)

Android version: RKQ1.200826.002

Android Security Update: 2021-07-01

I am getting a notification on my phone that does not specify which app is sending it. It looks pretty phishy and I have not tapped it yet, afraid it might be from an attacker or a virus. Especially that it is titled "Delete User" in Arabic. I have taken a screenshot and added to my question here. The Arabic title translates to "Delete User and the body translates to "Listen to your own voice"

I tried to block it but it cannot be blocked as every time I click on "more settings" it displays a message saying "the app wasn't found in the list of installed apps".

How is it possible that I receive a notification from an app that isn't installed on my phone? and could this be an attacker? I tried using the built in security scanner and it said there are no viruses.

What should i do to get rid of it?

[image: This is the notification message i see.]

Comment: Maybe some website you visited on your browser? Delete the cache of browser, possibly cookies too and check?

Comment: Could you also write the Arabic text on here, just in case we need it to do some research?

Comment: Sure, The Arabic text is:
مسح المستخدم
It translates to: Delete user

The 2nd line text is: استمع الي صوتك
Which translates to: Listen to your voice

Comment: I do allow notifications from my chrome browser, like both notifications above and below this one, but as you can see on the upper left corner, it specifies which app is sending it. This notification is like a ghost thing! No app, no references to anything and I am afraid it might be a phishing attack

Comment: Do you have a guest or additional user set up on your device? [Top searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+%3A+%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AD+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D9%85&oq=android+%3A+%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AD+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D9%85&aqs=chrome..69i57.6841j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) suggest that //Also tag the person whom you want to reply to - otherwise they won't get notified (e.g. @guy who commented)

Comment: kindly share output of *'adb shell dumpsys notification — noredact'*